# printing html entities using lxml in python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I'm trying to make a div element from the below string with html entities. Since my string contains html entities, `&` reserved char in the html entity is being escaped as `&amp;` in the output. Thus html entities are displayed as plain text. How can I avoid this so html entities are rendered properly?

```
s = 'Actress Adamari L&#243;pez And Amgen Launch Spanish-Language Chemotherapy: Myths Or Facts&#8482; Website And Resources'

div = etree.Element("div")
div.text = s

lxml.html.tostring(div)

output:
<div>Actress Adamari L&amp;#243;pez And Amgen Launch Spanish-Language Chemotherapy: Myths Or Facts&amp;#8482; Website And Resources</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify `encoding` while calling `tostring()`:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
>>> s = 'Actress Adamari L&#243;pez And Amgen Launch Spanish-Language Chemotherapy: Myths Or Facts&#8482; Website And Resources'
>>> div = fromstring(s)
>>> print tostring(div, encoding='unicode')
<p>Actress Adamari López And Amgen Launch Spanish-Language Chemotherapy: Myths Or Facts™ Website And Resources</p>
```

As a side note, you [should definitely use `lxml.html.tostring()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#creating-html-with-the-e-factory) while dealing with `HTML` data:

> Note that you should use `lxml.html.tostring` and not `lxml.tostring`.
>   `lxml.tostring(doc)` will return the XML representation of the document,
>   which is not valid HTML. In particular, things like `<script src="..."></script>` will be serialized as `<script src="..." />`, which completely confuses browsers.

Also see:

- [Serialising to Unicode strings](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#serialising-to-unicode-strings)